How to use Kafka Streams to query a topic with non-unique keys and return all records?
We have a single topic that has non-unique keys (client name) for the messages and I would like to query it using Kafka Streams by a value and return all the records (there could be lots of messages in the topic per client).
For example:

clienta returns 10 messages
clientb returns 7 messages

I am not fixed on "client" as the criteria initially.  I could also do it as:

range (not sure how)
prefix and materialize the data with a unique key like client-XXX

Right now I have this, and it works, but it seems like a terrible approach.
Topology:
@ApplicationScoped
class TopologyProducer {

    public static final String EVENTS_TOPIC = "clients.events";
    public static final String EVENTS_STORE = "clients.store";
    
    final ObjectMapperSerde<EventMessage> messageSerde = new ObjectMapperSerde<>(EventMessage.class);
    final ListSerde<EventMessage> listSerde = new ListSerde<>(ArrayList.class, messageSerde);

    @Produces
    public Topology getEventTopology() {

        final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        final KeyValueBytesStoreSupplier storeSupplier = Stores.inMemoryKeyValueStore(EVENTS_STORE);

        builder
            .stream(
                EVENTS_TOPIC,
                Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), messageSerde))
            .groupByKey()
            .aggregate(
                ArrayList::new,
                (key, value, aggregate) -> {
                    aggregate.add(value);
                    return aggregate;
                },
                Materialized.<String, List<EventMessage>>as(storeSupplier)
                    .withKeySerde(Serdes.String())
                    .withValueSerde(listSerde));

        return builder.build();
    }
}

Interactive Query
@ApplicationScoped
class InteractiveQueries {

    @Inject
    KafkaStreams streams;

    public List<EventMessage> findEvents(String client) {
        return getEvents().get(client);
    }

    private ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<String, List<EventMessage>> getEvents() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                return streams.store(fromNameAndType(
                    EVENTS_STORE,
                    QueryableStoreTypes.keyValueStore()));
            }
            catch (InvalidStateStoreException e) {
                // ignore, store not ready yet
            }
        }
    }
}

